# Java program to sort a sequence of numbers in a text file

Tags: java

I am stuck on my Java assignment right now. What I have to do is to write a program which will sort a sequence of numbers in a text file, and this program should read an arbitrary number of integers from a file, sort it and remove any duplicates and save the new list in the same file.

The program should ask the user for the name of the input file, and perform checks if the file exists, contains valid data, etc. The thing is that I have no idea even how to begin, I've been trying but couldn't reach the goal, couldn't even write couple of lines of code because I don't know how to start. I only know that I can use JFileChooser to prompt the user to choose a file.

Well, I know that this is not the right type of question because I had to show what I have done so far, or prove that I've tried some stuff, but the thing is that I couldn't do anything even though I've been trying for hours.

Comment: Please see: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: Well, if you have absolutely no idea at all, it's time to review what you've learned about coding in Java so far. If you can't even code the part to read the input, you really need to get help from your instructor.

Comment: I know how to read an input, but thought that showing that part of the code would not be much of a help, as the main problem in this program is a different thing rather than reading an input.

Comment: You need to break down your problem and identify the steps needed to accomplish your task. 1. Let a user input the file path. 2. Read the file into memory, in a way that will be beneficial for the next steps. 3. Filter duplicates. 4. Sort. The thing is, each of these problems can be approached independently. If you don't know how to accept human input, try hard coding the file path for now. Focus on reading a file into memory or start with a list/set of numbers and try to sort them.

Comment: Questions asking for *homework help* **must** include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it ([help], [ask]).

Comment: @J.Ill That's not how StackOverflow works. Please read [ask]. If anyone gives you full code he does something generally discouraged. That is why you only get answers giving high level explanations.

Comment: (I have edited the question to make it less like a request for free work. It is good if you have done some of it - please edit that into the question _promptly_ to show that you have done some prior work. That _might_ stop the question from being closed. Requests for homework completion, in any case, do ensure the asker misses a learning opportunity, and on top of that, their teaching institution may take action for academic dishonesty).

Comment: Could you actually delete the post please? As no one's apparently going to help me with the complete code, this post is just going to take up the memory on your web hosting, and will occasionally make some people mad who will stumble upon this post - a guy requesting a free work, wow. So, please, at least accept this request and delete the post. Thank you

Comment: The post can't be deleted while it is open, since it has had an accepted answer (and I believe even if you unaccept it, it won't become deletable). This is because once a helper has received credit for their good work, it would be unfair to remove it from them (which is what happens generally if a question is closed and deleted). However, it may yet close, in which case, it could become deletable.

Comment: The reason why readers are often touchy about naked requests for free work is that it does not respect the time and value of people's work, and it also is asking people to make a large effort in response to none at all.

Comment: To illustrate this principle: I _could_ go and ask an architect for some quickie drawings of a house extension I am thinking about, and ask her to whip them up for free, but it would be rude to do so. I can either choose to pay her for her time, or I can make an effort to learn how to do the drawings and then email her with a small and focussed question about them. She may well be willing to do the latter, and gladly, because she will see I have done my own research.

Comment: I hope this helps. Indeed, it should, since we encounter this sort of thing often here, and we are quite familiar on how to advise upon it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want help and not complete code:

1. Read a textfile: `FileReader` ...
2. ... line-by-line: `BufferedReader` and its `readLine()` method
3. Integer from text: `Integer.parseInt()` (assumption: there is one number per line)
4. Store Integers in something, which orders them, and removes duplicates: `TreeSet<Integer>`, and its `add()` method
5. Get back the numbers (ordered, duplicates removed): `iterator()` (of the same `TreeSet<Integer>`)
6. Writing a textfile: `PrintWriter`

There are some gaps, but reading the documentation and checking related examples will fill them.

---

Without any fancy/cryptic construct:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    TreeSet<Integer> numbers=new TreeSet<>();
    FileReader fr=new FileReader("numbers.txt");
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);
    String line;
    while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
        numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(line));
    }
    br.close();
    Iterator<Integer> it=numbers.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(it.next());
    }
    //PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter("result.txt");
    //while(it.hasNext()){
    //  pw.println(it.next());
    //}
    //pw.close();
}
```

The commented part would print the result into a file.

Test file: numbers.txt

```
34
2345
736
2435
7436
2345
2435
```

Comment: Well, basically I asked for a complete code, but I'll try to do it with this information if I manage to. Thanks

Comment: A`Scanner` to read the file is probably easier.

Comment: @daniu yes, of course, there are options.

Comment: Well, I still could not do it, could you please if you have time, write the complete code for me, if it won't be too much of an inconvenience for you? That would be a total lifesaver for me, and I will be forever grateful of you..

Comment: @J.Ill your homework, dear miss/mr.

Comment: Well, thank you! Now I see the path clearly.

Comment: @tevemadar: see the comment conversation under the question to see the disadvantages of doing free (home)work on Stack Overflow. The question author would have liked to get the free work, and then delete the question, which would remove the reputation credit you have earned, and would remove the answer from your Stack Overflow profile. Although you're welcome to answer these sorts of questions if you like, it's worth understanding why it may be best not to do so: it could be a waste of your time.

Comment: (Indeed, the question may still close, and it may be deleted thereafter, which will have the same effect).

Comment: @halfer While yes, I find that 20-25 minutes which have passed between OP saying they would try and than coming back that they could not do it, a bit too short, I also find this curriculum a bit strange. It is just the middle of a semester (2nd or 3rd month, depending on country), and people are expected to write a GUI application with Swing, file-handling and some moderately deep understanding on collections?

Comment: @halfer The deletion idea of OP came after they started get bashed in the comments, it was not their original intent in my opinion.

Comment: @tevemadar: perhaps, though I'd not be sure about that. However, they knew it was off-topic and posted it anyway, so... `:-)`

Answer (score 0):

So, you are trying to make a Swing application! And you are using JFileChooser, so there is no need to check if file exist or not as you won't see the file in the open window which doesn't exist.

Regarding sorting the file, you read the file content as buffer stream (line by line reading is possible) and add the line in a TreeSet<Integer> so that only unique value will be stored (so no duplication). At the end just write the TreeSet data to a file.

Comment: Could you please if you have time and a will, write a complete code for me? Thank you